# Adding a new OSGI bundle to local p2 repository

Tags: java, osgi

I have created a new OSGI bundle from an existing jar file. I have a local p2 repository which is set as a target platform in my eclipse. I directly copied this OSGI bundle to the local p2 repository. But my build says it cannot find the my new OSGI plugin. I manually added a new entry in artifacts.xml for this new bundle as well. But still no luck. Can anybody please help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [p2.publisher](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp) for that.

example:

```
java -jar <eclipseDirectory>/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_<version>.jar
   -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher
   -metadataRepository file:/<yourLocalRepo>
   -artifactRepository file:/<yourLocalRepo>
   -source <location with a sub-directory named plugin and/or features >
   -publishArtifacts
```

You need to replace eclipseDirectory and the version of the equinox launcher bundle.
Information is from here [Eclipse Wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Publisher#Features_And_Bundles_Publisher_Application)